# Cannot insert blob file as content version

Tags: apex, files, contentversion, contentdocument, webhooks

I'm trying to insert blob file as Content version into Salesforce. Im getting the response in my webhook, for which I have to make a callout to another endpoint to get the blob data. Once I got it, I'm trying to insert into Salesforce using content version and it is throwing me an error:

**INVALID_STATUS, Documents in a user's private library must always be owned by that user.: [OwnerId]**

Can anyone help me on this? I already tried multi solutions available over the internet, but still I failed to insert record as content version into Salesforce.

Also,I tried to insert it as attachment as well, then convert it to content version. Attachment was getting created, but while converting it to content version again the same error is coming.

Can someone help me on this? Any input is appreciated.